# No sound on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS RPi3

Tags: 18.04, sound, lubuntu, alsa, raspberrypi

I am trying to set up OP25 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B running a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (lubuntu-core desktop). The software installs fine, however I cannot get any sound out of the Pi, via HDMI or from the analog output. Here's what I have tried.

1. `aplay -l` returns `aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...`
2. Tried removing `pulseaudio` and `alsa`, reinstalling, does nothing.
3. Tried reconfiguring hdmi/3.5mm jack (`sudo amixer cset numid=3 1`), no result.
4. Tried using `inxi`, no audio devices found.
5. `modprobe snd_bcm2835` returns `[1948.563781] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: Failed to get DT property 'brcm,pwm-channels'`
6. Tried adding `dtparam=audio=on` to config.txt, no result.
7. Tried `speaker-test`, no result.

The Pi itself is not defective, when I installed Ubuntu MATE the sound worked fine. My preference is to have the server running lubuntu-core, as I only need minimal features.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into the boot FAT partition where there are some configuration files?  There you can enable or disable drivers.  It might be something there you need to change.

Comment: @Anders I have not, will try that. Thanks!